# Efficiently Running Newton Algorithm

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

This is related to another question I asked earlier. I want to run the newton method on a large dataset. Below is the code I created using a loop. I need to run it on ~50 million lines and the loop is quite unwieldy. Is there a more efficient way to run it using Pandas/Numpy/ect? Thanks in advance

```
In:
from pandas import *
from pylab import *
import pandas as pd
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import *
import scipy

df = DataFrame(list([100,2,34.1556,9,105,-100]))
df = DataFrame.transpose(df)
df = df.rename(columns={0:'Face',1:'Freq',2:'N',3:'C',4:'Mkt_Price',5:'Yield'})
df2= df
df = concat([df, df2])
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df

Out:
    Face    Freq    N        C Mkt_Price  Yield
0    100     2   34.1556     9   105    -100
1    100     2   34.1556     9   105    -100

In:
def Px(Rate):
    return Mkt_Price - (Face * ( 1 + Rate / Freq ) ** ( - N ) + ( C / Rate ) * ( 1 - (1 + ( Rate / Freq )) ** -N ) )

for count, row in df.iterrows():
        Face = row['Face']
        Freq = row['Freq']
        N = row['N']
        C = row['C']
        Mkt_Price = row['Mkt_Price']
        row['Yield'] = scipy.optimize.newton(Px, .1, tol=.0001, maxiter=100)
df

Out:
    Face    Freq   N         C  Mkt_Price   Yield
0    100     2   34.1556     9   105       0.084419
1    100     2   34.1556     9   105       0.084419
```

Comment: Do you really have 50M unique bonds?  If you converted your face, price, coupon to a standard unit and grouped, does that reduce the problem size?

Comment: Its about 40k bonds but each in time series with a different price, coupon, time to maturity, ect on each day.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility that pops into my mind is that you might do it vectorized. However, you must then throw away all conditional code, and just run the required amount of iterations.

The basic step in Newton-Raphson is always the same, so you do not need to have any conditional code. Your function `Px` looks as if it could be vectorized without any extra effort.

The steps are roughly:

```
def Px(Rate, Mkt_Price, Face, Freq, N, C):
    return Mkt_Price - (Face * ( 1 + Rate / Freq ) ** ( - N ) + ( C / Rate ) * ( 1 - (1 + ( Rate / Freq )) ** -N ) )

# initialize the iteration vector
y = 0.1 * np.zeros(num_rows)
# just a guess for the differentiation, might be smaller
h = 1e-6

# then iterate for a suitable number of iterations
for i in range(100):
    f = Px(y, Mkt_Price, Face, Freq, N, C)
    fp = Px(y+h, Mkt_Price, Face, Freq, N, C)
    y -= h * f / (fp - f)
```

After this you have the iteration results in `y`. I have assumed `Mkt_Price`, `Face`, etc. are 50-million-row vectors.

There will be billions of calculations, so this will still take maybe a dozen seconds. Also, there is no error checking, so if something goes wildly oscillating, there is nothing to warn you about it.

One way to make this better is to calculate the first differential analytically, as it can be done. The practical improvement may be small, though. You will have to experiment to find the best number of iterations. If the function converges fast (as I suppose), 20 iterations will be plenty.

The code is completely untested, but it should illustrate the idea.